# How to "quickly" cut and separate video into tracks (Davinci Resolve 18)?

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am brand new to Davinci Resolve, video recording, and editing in general.

I'm running Davinci Resolve Free 18.6.3 on Windows.

(Part of my issue in finding the answer(s) might be in my lack of terminology in this space, and Google is no longer my friend, so please stick with me here.)

I have a 5-minute video... it's an unscripted, random, incoherent mess.

I believe I can make it somewhat watchable by removing some parts and moving others.

I'm not suggesting that a bunch of transitions in a such a short video is good, but it'll be better than what I have (the scene is reasonably static), and I don't have an opportunity to re-shoot it.

Here's the workflow I would like to figure out...

1. Watch the video, add markers (Done)
2. Cut at every marker (I accomplished this with Arrow Up/Down, Ctrl-B)
3. "Split" or "separate" each resulting "clip" into a new track.

Is there a quicker way to accomplish #2? All markers at once?

Is there a quick way to accomplish #3? I can "Add Track" then drag and drop with the mouse, one by one, but I'm looking for something quicker (preferably with keystrokes).